# Generating random code per client ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to be able to generate a random & unique code for a given client ID a given number of times. The code I have below *nearly* fulfils this objective perfectly, I say only nearly because the call to the RAND() function is not updated, the value is the same regardless. I guess you could say then the code fails to fulfil this objective.

The code must be 2 banks of 4 digits separated by a hyphen so 0123-4567 for example. I need the possibility of the code beginning with a zero and must only contain numeric values other than the separator.

Other things you may need to know are: the client ID is a uniqueidentifier. The FriendlyName and FriendlyKey values must be unique. Codes will generally be generated in batches of 50. The random element of this must be included to try and prevent any guessing of valid codes. Each code has its own primary key (uniqueidentifier).

I understand that as this process matures the possiblity of generating a duplicate code will increase but given that the codes are generated against a client ID, there are 100 million combinations (0000-0000 - 9999-9999) available for each client and for the purposes of this exercise, this possibility isn't a consideration. Also, the time needed to check against the existing dataset is going to increase but again, for the purposes of this exercise, this consideration can be safely ignored.

Thanks for reading. Hope someone can help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateAccessCodeForClient
@clientID uniqueidentifier,
@total int

as

DECLARE @numCodes INT = @total;
DECLARE @startNum INT = 1;
DECLARE @nums TABLE(n NVARCHAR(9) NOT NULL);
DECLARE @results TABLE(Code NVARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, CLIENTID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @nums
SELECT TOP (@numCodes) RIGHT('0' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) + (@startNum - 1) AS NVARCHAR), 9) n
FROM sys.all_objects s1
          CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects s2;

INSERT [AccessCodes]([PrimaryKey], [Code], [FriendlyKey], [FriendlyName], [AdditionalInfo], [CreatedDate], [ModifiedDate], [CreatedByID], [ModifiedByID], [ClientID])
OUTPUT Inserted.Code, Inserted.PrimaryKey, Inserted.ClientID
INTO @results
select NEWID(), 
    concat(LEFT(SUBSTRING (RTRIM(RAND()) + SUBSTRING(RTRIM(RAND()),3,11), 3,11),4) , '-', LEFT(SUBSTRING (RTRIM(RAND()) + SUBSTRING(RTRIM(RAND()),3,11), 3,11),4)), 
     n, 
     'fName' + n, 
     'addInfo' + n, 
     getdate(), 
     getdate(), 
     'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff',
     'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff',
     'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff'
FROM @nums;

SELECT Code, ID, CLIENTID
FROM @results
ORDER BY Code DESC;
```

Comment: Why don't you generate a GUID with NEWID()?

Comment: how many clients (clientId's) do you have?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Not an option I'm afraid. The code must follow the pattern given above. You're right though that it would make things easier.

Comment: @Tanner - At present, not many but the plan is that this number will grow in the future.

Comment: You can convert a GUID to binary then format it as numbers

Comment: Cant you simply have an identity or sequence, that will generate numbers 1,2,3... casr to string, then fill zeros 00000001, 00000002, 00000003, then add dash?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Normally, yes. However in this particular case the need for randomness is present to stop these codes being guessed. Obviously there is always a chance that someone could guess even a random code, but if they are sequential, it becomes way easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        LEFT(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS BIGINT)), 4)
        ,'-'
        ,RIGHT(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS BIGINT)), 4)
        ) AS [RandomCode]
```

If you would like the first random integer to be always 0. You could do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT (
    0
    ,LEFT(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS BIGINT)), 3)
    ,'-'
    ,RIGHT(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS BIGINT)), 4)
    ) AS [RandomCode]
```

Comment: The first digit of this result doesn't appear sufficiently random. It is heavily skewed toward 1, moderately skewed toward 2, and evenly divided between the remaining digits, which I'm sure is due to the limits of INT.

Comment: Interesting!....It doesn't appear to be skewed when I am running it. I am getting quite random numbers from both queries.

Comment: Proposed modification:
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT RIGHT('00000000'+ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)),8) AS rndm)
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(rndm,4),'-',RIGHT(rndm,4)) FROM CTE

Comment: Proposed modification 2:
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT RIGHT(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS BIGINT),8) AS rndm)
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(rndm,4),'-',RIGHT(rndm,4)) FROM CTE

Comment: @Rookie13 Will plug this in and get back to you, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Sadly no. Similar to @Matt, I was getting some heavily skewed responses, including none at all beginning with 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Hmm that's odd....I tried this on sqlfiddle and it seems to be working just fine. Check this out: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c403/1/0

Comment: I can't really enforce the leading zero, the possibility needs to exist that the code can start with any digit from 0 - 9. Removing the 0 from the concat statement produces the same results as earlier - no codes at all starting with 0 - 3.

Comment: Interestingly, it's only the 1st group of 4 where this restriction comes into existence, the 2nd bank behaves perfectly. Switching LEFT for RIGHT seems to work.

Comment: Leaving the code as you supplied it also produced no results starting with a 9 either, every single code began with 4 - 8 inclusive. It's a resultset I wouldn't have anticipated at all. Weird.

Comment: That is quite strange. Perhaps if switching left for right seems to be working, you could concatenate two newid() with only right 4 digits. That's still surprising to me that the results are skewed.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to amend Rookie13's answer with my own tweaks. Although performance probably isn't a big issue for this case, the below code performs fewer operations (calls NewID() only once, for instance), and uses only the last 8 digits of a BIGINT as the random number.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( SELECT RIGHT(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS BIGINT),8) AS rndm )
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(rndm,4),'-',RIGHT(rndm,4)) 
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Admittedly there is a 1/100 billion chance that the BIGINT value will have fewer than 8 digits, resulting in a suboptimal random value. But I can live with that margin of error.